# Javascript - Remove Image from element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to remove the image from the following html, but am running into trouble. I am able to specify the ID is java script but am not sure how to remove the associated img.

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" id="my_banner_image" style="display: block;">
    <img width="970" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/970x250.png" boarder="0">
</a>
```

I have tried using, but am not quite sure how to specify the img.

```
var element = document.getElementById("my_banner_image");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate img element using `querySelector` method:

```
document.getElementById("my_banner_image")
    .querySelector('img')
    .remove()
```

It will remove the first img tag inside element with id `my_banner_image`